# Showing data from one table and filter data from another mysql table in datatable js using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, filter, datatable

I'm developing Accounting CRM using Codeigniter. Below is the final Output. In this i'm using two **tables** named as **statements_codes** (contains list of the all the codes) and **statements_records** (contains all the amounts entered from the user form).

[image: Below is the final Output]

Table Structure is below
[image: Table Structure is below]

I'm showing the all the codes list from statements_codes table and counting the amount by monthly from statements_records table and showing as combined using Datatable **Ref:(1st Image)**

When I applying filter to the table its filter the data from the statements_codes tables only. But i Want to filter and calculate from the statements_records table. **For Ex:** If i filter the data by January it should filter the data from date column in statements_records table for each account codes.

Below is the **Controller code** for the statements

```
   public function statements($report_year = ''){
    
    $this->load->model('statements_model'); 
    $data['title']     = 'Statements GL Report';
    $data['years']     = $this->statements_model->get_statements_years();
    $data['codes']     = $this->statements_model->get_code();       

    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        
        $aColumns = [
                 'id',
                 'cat_id',        
                 'subcat_id',    
                 'group_id',   
                 'subgroup',    
                 'code',
                 'title',
                 'created_on'
            ];
            $join = [];
            $where  = [];
            $filter = [];
           
        
            $codes  = $this->ci->statements_model->get_code();
            $_codes = [];
            foreach ($codes as $c) {
                if ($this->ci->input->post('statements_by_code_' . $c['id'])) {
                    array_push($_codes, $c['id']);
                }
            }
            if (count($_codes) > 0) {
                array_push($filter, 'AND id IN (' . implode(', ', $_codes) . ')');
            }

            $_months = [];
            for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) {
                if ($this->ci->input->post('statements_by_month_' . $m)) {
                    array_push($_months, $m);
                }
            }
            if (count($_months) > 0) {
                array_push($filter, 'AND MONTH(created_on) IN (' . implode(', ', $_months) . ')');                  
            }
            $months_f   = (count($_months) > 0 ? $_months : 'all');
            $Months_Arr = (is_array($_months) && count($_months) > 0 ? implode(', ', $_months) : 'all');
            
            $years  = $this->ci->statements_model->get_statements_years();
            $_years = [];
            foreach ($years as $year) {
                if ($this->ci->input->post('year_' . $year['year'])) {
                    array_push($_years, $year['year']);
                }
            }                        

            if (count($_years) > 0) {
                array_push($filter, 'AND YEAR(created_on) IN (' . implode(', ', $_years) . ')');
                if(count($_years) == 1){
                    $report_year           = $_years[0];
                }
                else{
                    $report_year           = $_years;
                }
            }
        

            if (count($filter) > 0) {
                array_push($where, 'AND (' . prepare_dt_filter($filter) . ')');
            }
                     
            $sIndexColumn = 'id';
            $sTable       = db_prefix() . 'statements_codes';                
            $result       = data_tables_init($aColumns, $sIndexColumn, $sTable, $join, $where, []);            
            $output       = $result['output'];
            $rResult      = $result['rResult'];             
            $footer_data  = [
                'gl'              => number_format(0,2),
                'ob'              => number_format(0,2),
                'j_cre'           => number_format(0,2),
                'j_deb'           => number_format(0,2),
                'j_tot'           => number_format(0,2),
                'f_cre'           => number_format(0,2),
                'f_deb'           => number_format(0,2),
                'f_tot'           => number_format(0,2),
                'm_cre'           => number_format(0,2),
                'm_deb'           => number_format(0,2),
                'm_tot'           => number_format(0,2),
                'a_cre'           => number_format(0,2),
                'a_deb'           => number_format(0,2),
                'a_tot'           => number_format(0,2),
                'my_cre'          => number_format(0,2),
                'my_deb'          => number_format(0,2),
                'my_tot'          => number_format(0,2),
                'jn_cre'          => number_format(0,2),
                'jn_deb'          => number_format(0,2),
                'jn_tot'          => number_format(0,2),
                'jl_cre'          => number_format(0,2),
                'jl_deb'          => number_format(0,2),
                'jl_tot'          => number_format(0,2),
                'au_cre'          => number_format(0,2),
                'au_deb'          => number_format(0,2),
                'au_tot'          => number_format(0,2),
                's_cre'           => number_format(0,2),
                's_deb'           => number_format(0,2),
                's_tot'           => number_format(0,2),
                'o_cre'           => number_format(0,2),
                'o_deb'           => number_format(0,2),
                'o_tot'           => number_format(0,2),
                'n_cre'           => number_format(0,2),
                'n_deb'           => number_format(0,2),
                'n_tot'           => number_format(0,2),
                'd_cre'           => number_format(0,2),
                'd_deb'           => number_format(0,2),
                'd_tot'           => number_format(0,2),
                'c_cre'           => number_format(0,2),
                'c_deb'           => number_format(0,2),
                'c_tot'           => number_format(0,2),
                'fn_deb'          => number_format(0,2),
                'fn_cre'          => number_format(0,2),
                'fn_tot'          => number_format(0,2)
            ];        
  }
}
```

**Filter Template View Code**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
    if(!isset($filter_table_name)){
        $filter_table_name = '.table-statementsreport';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="_filters _hidden_inputs hidden">
    <?php 
    $z = 1;
    foreach($years as $year){
       if(count($years) == $z){
            echo form_hidden('year_'.$year['year'],$year['year']);
       }
      else{
          echo form_hidden('year_'.$year['year']);
      }
       $z++;
    }
    for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) {
      echo form_hidden('statements_by_month_'.$m);
   }
 
    foreach($codes as $code){
       echo form_hidden('statements_by_code_'.$code['id']);
    }

    ?>
   </div>
   <div class="btn-group pull-right mleft4 btn-with-tooltip-group _filter_data" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="<?php echo _l('filter_by'); ?>">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right width300">
    <?php if(count($years) > 0){ $y = 1; ?>
            
        <?php foreach($years as $year){ if($y == count($years)){  ?>
            
            <li class="active statements-filter-year">
                <a href="#" data-cview="year_<?php echo $year['year']; ?>" onclick="dt_custom_view(<?php echo $year['year']; ?>,'<?php echo $filter_table_name; ?>','year_<?php echo $year['year']; ?>'); return false;"><?php echo $year['year']; ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php } else{ ?>
             <li class="statements-filter-year">
                <a href="#" data-cview="year_<?php echo $year['year']; ?>" onclick="dt_custom_view(<?php echo $year['year']; ?>,'<?php echo $filter_table_name; ?>','year_<?php echo $year['year']; ?>'); return false;"><?php echo $year['year']; ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php } $y++; } } ?>        
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <li class="divider months-divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left statements-filter-month-wrapper">
                  <a href="#" tabindex="-1"><?php echo _l('months'); ?></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
                    <?php for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) { ?>
                      <li class="statements-filter-month"><a href="#" data-cview="statements_by_month_<?php echo $m; ?>" onclick="dt_custom_view(<?php echo $m; ?>,'<?php echo $filter_table_name; ?>','statements_by_month_<?php echo $m; ?>'); return false;"><?php echo _l(date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1))); ?></a></li>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </ul>
              </li>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <?php if(count($codes) > 0){ ?>
                <li class="divider"></li>
            <?php } ?>                
                <li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left statements-filter-code-wrapper">
                  <a href="#" tabindex="-1"><?php echo 'ACCT Codes'; ?></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
                    <?php foreach($codes as $code){  ?>
                      <li class="statements-filter-code">
                        <a href="#" data-cview="statements_by_code_<?php echo $code['id']; ?>" onclick="dt_custom_view('<?php echo $code['id']; ?>','<?php echo $filter_table_name; ?>','statements_by_code_<?php echo $code['id']; ?>'); return false;">
                            <?php echo ''.$code['title']; ?>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

**Datatable View Code**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel_s">
                <div class="panel-body">                        
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info pull-left" ><?php echo 'Balance Sheet'; ?></a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info pull-left" style="margin-left:15px;"><?php echo 'Income Statement'; ?></a>
                    <?php $this->load->view('admin/statements/filter_by_template'); ?>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-with-tooltip toggle-small-view hidden-xs" onclick="toggle_small_view('.table-statementsreport','#statements_records'); return false;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo _l('invoices_toggle_table_tooltip'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">            
        <div class="col-md-12" id="small-table">
            <div class="panel_s">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table dt-table-loading table-statementsreport">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="pre_header">
                                <th colspan="7"></th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">January</th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">February</th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">March</th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">April</th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">May</th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">June</th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">July</th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">August</th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">September</th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">October</th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">November</th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">December</th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">Closing</th>
                                <th colspan="3" class="sep">Total</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>ACCT Code</th>
                                <th>Account Title</th>
                                <th>Subgroup</th>
                                <th>General Ledger</th>
                                <th>Opening Balance</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>Debit</th>
                                <th>Credit</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="gl"></td>
                                <td class="ob"></td>
                                <td class="j_deb"></td>
                                <td class="j_cre"></td>
                                <td class="j_tot"></td>
                                <td class="f_deb"></td>
                                <td class="f_cre"></td>
                                <td class="f_tot"></td>
                                <td class="m_deb"></td>
                                <td class="m_cre"></td>
                                <td class="m_tot"></td>
                                <td class="a_deb"></td>
                                <td class="a_cre"></td>
                                <td class="a_tot"></td>
                                <td class="my_deb"></td>
                                <td class="my_cre"></td>
                                <td class="my_tot"></td>
                                <td class="jn_deb"></td>
                                <td class="jn_cre"></td>
                                <td class="jn_tot"></td>
                                <td class="jl_deb"></td>
                                <td class="jl_cre"></td>
                                <td class="jl_tot"></td>
                                <td class="au_deb"></td>
                                <td class="au_cre"></td>
                                <td class="au_tot"></td>
                                <td class="s_deb"></td>
                                <td class="s_cre"></td>
                                <td class="s_tot"></td>
                                <td class="o_deb"></td>
                                <td class="o_cre"></td>
                                <td class="o_tot"></td>
                                <td class="n_deb"></td>
                                <td class="n_cre"></td>
                                <td class="n_tot"></td>
                                <td class="d_deb"></td>
                                <td class="d_cre"></td>
                                <td class="d_tot"></td>
                                <td class="c_deb"></td>
                                <td class="c_cre"></td>
                                <td class="c_tot"></td>
                                <td class="fn_deb"></td>
                                <td class="fn_cre"></td>
                                <td class="fn_tot"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 small-table-right-col">
            <div id="statements_records" class="hide">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Datatable Js Code**

```
 $(function(){

   var filter_selector_helper = '.statements-filter-year,.statements-filter-month-wrapper,.statments-filter-month,.months-divider';

    var Statementsreport_ServerParams = {};
       $.each($('._hidden_inputs._filters input'),function(){
        Statementsreport_ServerParams[$(this).attr('name')] = '[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]';
    });


   initDataTable('.table-statementsreport', window.location.href, 'undefined', 'undefined', Statementsreport_ServerParams, [2, 'asc']).columns([0,1]).visible(false, false);            

   $('.table-statementsreport').on('draw.dt',function(){
    var statementsReportsTable = $(this).DataTable();
    var sums = statementsReportsTable.ajax.json().sums;
    $(this).find('tfoot').addClass('bold');
    $(this).find('tfoot td').eq(0).html("<?php echo _l('expenses_report_total'); ?>");
    $(this).find('tfoot td.gl').html(sums.gl);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.ob').html(sums.ob);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.j_deb').html(sums.j_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.j_cre').html(sums.j_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.j_tot').html(sums.j_tot);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.f_deb').html(sums.f_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.f_cre').html(sums.f_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.f_tot').html(sums.f_tot);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.m_deb').html(sums.m_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.m_cre').html(sums.m_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.m_tot').html(sums.m_tot);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.a_deb').html(sums.a_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.a_cre').html(sums.a_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.a_tot').html(sums.a_tot);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.my_deb').html(sums.my_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.my_cre').html(sums.my_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.my_tot').html(sums.my_tot);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.jn_deb').html(sums.jn_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.jn_cre').html(sums.jn_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.jn_tot').html(sums.jn_tot);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.jl_deb').html(sums.jl_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.jl_cre').html(sums.jl_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.jl_tot').html(sums.jl_tot);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.au_deb').html(sums.au_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.au_cre').html(sums.au_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.au_tot').html(sums.au_tot);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.s_deb').html(sums.s_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.s_cre').html(sums.s_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.s_tot').html(sums.s_tot);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.o_deb').html(sums.o_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.o_cre').html(sums.o_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.o_tot').html(sums.o_tot);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.n_deb').html(sums.n_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.n_cre').html(sums.n_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.n_tot').html(sums.n_tot);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.d_deb').html(sums.d_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.d_cre').html(sums.d_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.d_tot').html(sums.d_tot);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.c_deb').html(sums.c_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.c_cre').html(sums.c_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.c_tot').html(sums.c_tot);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.fn_deb').html(sums.fn_deb);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.fn_cre').html(sums.fn_cre);
    $(this).find('tfoot td.fn_tot').html(sums.fn_tot);
})
   });
```

Anyone can please help me to fix this. Thanks in Advance